# What is the time complexity of the dividing an array into n subarrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I've written the following program which splits an array into size subarrays using JS's slice function, I'm trying to figure out the time complexity for this algorithm:

```
function chunk(array, size) {
    if(array.length < size)
        return [array];

    let result = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i += size)
            result.push(array.slice(i, i+size));

    return result;
}
```

My current understanding is that the complexity is O(n*size) because we iterate through the whole array size times. If someone could help me figure this solution it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `O(n)`.

You iterate through the array `n/size` times, and each iteration is `O(size)` because it makes a slice of `size` elements. So the total amount of work is `n/size * size`, which is `n`.